# Powershell CSV Insert variable

Tags: powershell

I'm new and I would like to add in my csv and seperate with my variable the csv in multiple column.
I try to use ADD-CONTENT but it is only in one column.
my variable is :

```
$global:deltaNv_NOM_APPRENANT = @()
$global:deltaNv_PRENOM_APPRENANT = @()
$global:deltaNv_NOM_NET_UTILISATEUR_APPRENANT = @()
$global:deltaNv_PASSWORD_NET_UTILISATEUR_APPRE = @()
$global:deltaNv_MDP_AD = @()
$global:deltaNv_EMAIL_COURRIER = @()
$global:deltaNv_TELEPHONE_COURRIER = @()
$global:deltaNv_PORTABLE_COURRIER = @()
$global:deltaNv_ABREGE_GROUPE_APPRENANT = @()
```

I would like to put them into the csv like that :
[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF0SX.png)

Comment: import your CSV with `Import-Csv`, iterate thru the resulting collection, build a new `[PCustomObject]` with the added property and all the desired props from the current object, save that to a new collection, and - finally - send that out with `Export-Csv`.

Comment: [pscustomobject]@{
    NOM_APPRENANT = $deltaNv_NOM_APPRENANT
    PRENOM_APPRENANT = $deltaPartis_PRENOM_APPRENANT
} | Export-Csv -notype"C:\Users\tl\Desktop\STAGE\PSCSVAD\backups\ADUsers_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).csv" -delimiter ";"

Comment: It show to me System.Object[]

Comment: The csv is expecting a string to be output for the values. Write out the rest of the volumes and assign it the property value

Comment: @thibautledig - PLEASE, put the code _in your Question_ where it can be read easily. [*grin*]